# android: click event that's not being consumed

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I need to create a click event, that's not being consumed, so that an underlying adapter receives the touch event.
I cant use an `OnClickListener`, because that would consume the event.
I tried my best with `OnTouchListener`, but if I return `true` the event gets consumed and if I return `false` the listener only registers `ACTION_DOWN` events.
How can I react on a click, but if its not a click the adapter will receive the move?

EDIT:
I'm using a `lorentzos.swipecards` `SwipeFlingAdapterView`, which uses touch-move-events. I put a layout over half of the view of the items of the adapter, which need to react on click events. But I either can't implement the click event, since I can't catch two events in a row without consuming them, or I can't have the `SwipeFlingAdapterView` react on the touch-move-event, since I, well, consumed it in the click event.

Don't know what sourcecode to share, since I tried many different ways and nothing works.

Comment: could you please put your code and explain your criteria ?